# Filtering data from csv file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to filter a massive CSV export containing phone records. The file contains 97 columns and the rows depend on how many calls have been made. Current there are 838.239 rows. I have trouble with excel loading this much data so I've turned to linux.

Out of the 97 columns, I'm only interested in columns  13, 28 and 53. I have managed to extract the data using -

```
cut -d, -f 1-12,14-27,29-52,54-97 --complement cdr_export.csv >> filtered_CDR.CSV
```

I'm stuck on how to filter the rows.

```
Telephone       ic_hg       og_hg
111111111111    server03    slo.out
222222222222    HG_1        server02
333333333333    HG_1        server03
444444444444    Trunk       server02
555555555555    Trunk       server03
666666666666    server614   slo.out
777777777777    HG_1        server563
888888888888    server563   slo.out
999999999999    HG_2        server563
```

The only data I need is -

- Any telephone number
- ic_hg = HG_1 or HG_2 & og_hg = slo.out

Example -

222222222222    HG_1     slo.out

222222222222    HG_2     slo.out

any other combinations can be removed.

Comment: Your desired output is **NOT** csv, btw, but apparently fixed-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with `awk`:

```
awk '($2 == "HG_1" || $2 == "HG2") || $3 == "slo.out" { print $1 }' filtered_CDR.CSV
111111111111
222222222222
333333333333
666666666666
777777777777
888888888888
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as expected. if the data is saved into a text file it will sort the data without issue, If it's in a excel csv and the data is in separate columns it returns no results. I also didn't explain myself very well. The og_hg must always = slo.out

Comment: You can pipe your previous command into awk to avoid saving into a text file: `cut … | awk '(…) { print $1 }'`. Actually, you can avoid using `cut` altogether and just process with awk the columns you need: just replace `$1` with `$13` to reference not the 1st but the 13th column etc. If `og_hg` must always be equal to `slo.out` you just need to turn the or (`||`) preceding such condition into an and (`&&`).

Comment: Hey etuardu, sorry i'm really stuck with turning the || into an AND condition 

awk '($2 == "HG_1" || $2 == "HG2") && $3 == "slo.out" { print $1 }' filtered_CDR.CSV

This provided no results

Comment: Your command seems to be correct. Please double check if such condition is satisfied for any line in your input data

Comment: By using awk '{ print $1 }'  allowed me to see my data was separated by commas. Starting the line with awk -F',' allows this to work perfectly. sorry my fault and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe it through a `grep`.

```
cut -d, -f 1-12,14-27,29-52,54-97 --complement cdr_export.csv |
  grep -E 'HG_[12][[:space:]]*slo[.]out' >> filtered_CDR.CSV
```

or maybe an `awk`

```
$: awk -F, '$53 ~ /^slo.out$/ && $28 ~ /^HG_[12]$/{ 
     print print $13"\t"$28"\t"$53}' cdr_export.csv >> filtered_CDR.CSV
```

I used tabs in the `awk` output. YMMV.